# C++ - Which are variable by " Uint "?

Tags: c++, c, uint

Which are variable by " Uint "? is that there are " Uint8 ", " Uint16 ", etc ...

But what are they ?

Now I have some time using C ++ but I have never needed to use these variables and cause me curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: check for a `typedef`. Most likely, it should be typedef to `uint32_t`or similar.

Comment: If you mean `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc - look in [`cstdint.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint). Sometimes you want an integer with a specific number of bits, e.g. if you're doing some sort of fixed-point arithmetic. Perhaps you haven't found a use for such types, and then you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: Most probably they are typedefs from a header file you included. These aren't any standard types though. Those are defined in the [`stdint.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint` is not a standard type. On some system `uint` is `typedef`ed as

```
typedef unsigned int uint ;
```

Comment: @leemes; What do you mean by other way?

Comment: I think @leemes meant `typedef unsigned int uint;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Oops! That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

`uint` is not a basic data type as mentioned in the standard. Sometimes, to make a variable to have constant size across platform [to enable portability], some `typedef`s are used.

You can have a look at [cstdint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) header for more info.

With best assumption, `uint` should be a typedef to `uint32_t`

```
typedef uint32_t uint;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned long  uint32_t;
typedef signed   char  int8_t;
typedef signed   short int16_t;
typedef signed   long  int32_t;

It can help you..
```

if you are dealing with variable base on it's size then you can declare it like this

Comment: Reinvents `<cstdint>` and isn't even correct at that. Even ignoring the more exotic systems whose `CHAR_BIT > 8`, this will still break spectacularly on LP64 systems.

Comment: Thank You for notifying mistake, it will help me